# How to shift this array to the right

Tags: java

I need to shift this everything in the array 1 index to right, so if i input `list.add("E", 1);`, then I should get `A,E,B,C,D`

```
/** Moves elements from index..rear-1 one index to the right. */

private void shiftRight(int index) {
 /** stores elements of list. */
  T[] elements;

/** index of next insertion point; number of elements in list. */
  int rear;


assert !isFull();
    // you must fill this in

      for (index = 0; index < rear-1; index++) {
         elements[index] = elements[index+1];
      }
   }
```

Comment: create new array of length+1, copy left side, insert element, copy right side.

Comment: If you don’t want to create another array remember that when swapping values between 2 variables the standard approach is to use a third temp variable and you can do the same here.

Comment: I'm sorry as my fluency in java isn't the best so i was wondering how adding the third temp variable may look?

Comment: If you guys could visually demonstrate that would be amazing, that is how i grasp this best @Antoniossss

Comment: @waterygatorade its not about fluency in java because array is not java's invention. Besides, judging from snipped you have shown, you already know syntax of constructs required to this task.

Answer (score 0):

This is exaclt implementation of my comment

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] baseArr = {1, 2, 8, 9};
        Integer insertedElement = 255;
        Integer insertionIndex = 1;

        Integer[] result = new Integer[baseArr.length + 1]; //create array longer by 1 element

        System.arraycopy(baseArr, 0, result, 0, insertionIndex); //copy beginning of the array to insertion point
        result[insertionIndex] = insertedElement; // insert element
        System.arraycopy(baseArr, insertionIndex, result, insertionIndex+1 , result.length - insertionIndex -1); //copy rest to the array after insertion point

        System.out.println("Input:"+Arrays.asList(baseArr));
        System.out.println("Output:"+Arrays.asList(result));
    }
```

See [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) for details about usiage

Answer (score 0):

The for loop should start at rear instead

```
  for (int i = rear; i > index; i--)
  {
     elements[i] = elements[i - 1];
  }
```

}